# How to call a Dialog Function From another Class in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to Call a Dialog Function from another Class File in flutter what is the Proper Way of doing That...

File1:-

```
 import 'package:eg/eg/dialog_file.dart'

    floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            onPressed: () {
            // This is where I want to call the function
            },
            backgroundColor: Colors.black,
            child: Container(
              child: Icon(
                icons.add,
                size: 23,
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

File2:-

```
    showMyDialog(parentContext) {
    return showDialog(
      context: parentContext,
      builder: (context) {
        return SimpleDialog(
          title: Text("Title"),
          children: <Widget>[
            SimpleDialogOption(
              child: Text("Option1"),
              onPressed: function1,
            ),
            SimpleDialogOption(
              child: Text("Option2"),
              onPressed: function2,
            ),
            SimpleDialogOption(
              child: Text("Option3"),
              onPressed: function3,
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

So the Dialog Function have onPressed Functions that are in the File2 so I am unable to write a custom dialog Function in File1

how could I achieve this?

Comment: You should provide some more context so I can be of better help. However, if you make the 'showMyDialog' method static, then 'File2.showMyDialog();' You can run the dialog by doing

Comment: @SalihCan it does not work 'function1', 'function2' and 'function3' gives the error "Instance members can't be accessed from a static method.
Try removing the reference to the instance member, or removing the keyword 'static' from the method."

Comment: The code you provided doesn't quite do what you want to do, so I can only offer limited help. According to the error you should make function1,2,3 static.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't mention where your `function1` etc... come from but in general here is one way call a dialog from another class. I make them static so I don't have to create an instance of the class.

```
class Dialogs {
  static Future<void> showMyDialog(parentContext) {
    return showDialog(
      context: parentContext,
      builder: (context) {
        return SimpleDialog(
          title: Text("Title"),
          children: <Widget>[
            SimpleDialogOption(child: Text("Option1"), onPressed: () {}),
            SimpleDialogOption(child: Text("Option2"), onPressed: () {}),
            SimpleDialogOption(child: Text("Option3"), onPressed: () {})
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

And here's an example of a button that will display the above dialog by passing in the context from the build method that it is inside of.

```
 ElevatedButton(
    onPressed: () => Dialogs.showMyDialog(context),
     child: Text('Dialog'),
 ),
```

Answer (score -1):

You should try below answer :

> First write your Dialog Function in other class

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
 return Container(
    color: Colors.white30,
    child:AlertDialog(
    title: Text(
       'name',
       style: TextStyle(
       fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    ),
    content: Text(
      'name',
       style: TextStyle(
       fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
      ),
      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
    ),
    actions: [
       TextButton(
        onPressed: () => Navigator.of(context).pop(),
        child: Text('OK'),
       )
     ],
   ),
  );
}
```

> Then write dialog class function in other class or where you call it like below:

```
onPressed: () {
   Navigator.push(
   context,
   MaterialPageRoute(
     builder: (context) => CampaignData(),
    ),
   );
  },
```